# Do I need special paint for drywall ceilings?

Tags: drywall, painting

Is there a paint specific for painting drywall ceilings? I'd assume such paint must possess certain features that make it not "fall" off ceilings :) Does it normally contain primer, or should I consider priming the ceiling in advance?

Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. Use any paint you like that's designed for interior use on drywall. Whether you use primer depends on what surface you're painting. You haven't told us.

Comment: I usually use a drywall specific primer.  It's cheap, and does the job of sealing the drywall paper so the top coats can go on better.

Comment: I would use a PVA primer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen paint labelled and marketed as "ceiling paint" with accompanying wording either suggesting that it is "thicker" for "minimum splatter", or that it provides a very "flat finish" suitable to brighten up ceilings without drawing attention or creating shiny spots.

I have seen no authoritative source for any of this.   It seems to be 100% marketing.

Where they say "thicker" they never say thicker than what, or how much thicker, or what that even means exactly, and the same brands always tout "less spattering" as a feature of other paints too.

Where they say "flatter" .... they always have all possible finishes from ultra flat to high gloss, and the one sold as "ceiling" is not more flat than the otherwise flattest one.  Or is it?  Nobody knows, because the marketing is purposely ambiguous.

Here is my attitude: On a previously painted white ceiling in good condition being re-painted in white, what you need is a cheap-ass paint that will allow you to spend money on more important things.   On new drywall you need a really good primer and a decent white paint.  Probably flat, but if you want an eggshell or glossy ceiling go for it.    If you have a big problem with paint dripping off the surfaces you paint what you need is to re-examine your technique and tools.  You don't need special paint.

To answer the specific question: I would definitely prime a fresh drywall ceiling.  Some paints are *also* primers and you might get away with two or three coats of the same product rather than a separate primer.  Really depends on the brand and on how closely you'll be scrutinizing the finish.

Comment: Where "marketing" is the short form of "horse food that's been processed through a horse already" ;-) Yeah, if paint "fell" off ceilings, it would also "fall" off walls...

Comment: I like that a newbie who just wants to paint a ceiling and is less inquisitive than OP can buy a can of "ceiling paint" and have a decent chance of success.  I don't find that offensive.   Now let's talk about "breakfast sausage", similarly marketed for usage and not content, but possibly in fact made as you suggest. :)